# Check if all items in RecyclerView have the same value (google Firestore)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to chceck if all items on adapter have a boolean value = true

Then based on result i have to change floatingActionButton color.
I have no idea how to do it.
Here is my Adapter:

```
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference basementReference = db.collection("basement");
private TableAdapter tableAdapter;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton basement = findViewById(R.id.button_basement);
    basement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    setUpRecyclerView();
}
private void setUpRecyclerView(){
    final Query query = basementReference.orderBy("tableNumber",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Table> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Table>()
            .setQuery(query, Table.class)
            .build();

    tableAdapter = new TableAdapter(options);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(tableAdapter);  tableAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new TableAdapter.OnItemCLickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Table table = documentSnapshot.toObject(Table.class);

                if(table.isTableOccupied()){
                    basementReference.document(documentSnapshot.getId()).update("tableOccupied",false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {


                }else {
                    basementReference.document(documentSnapshot.getId()).update("tableOccupied",true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {


    }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    tableAdapter.startListening();
}
```

please help. i tthink i need to do it in my adapter class, but if there is other solution i'll be glad to follow :)

tableAdapter class: 
class TableAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter {

```
public TableAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Table> options) {
    super(options);
}

private OnItemCLickListener onItemCLickListener;
private int occupiedMarker = 0;

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TableHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Table model) {
    holder.textViewTableNumber.setText(model.getTableNumber());
    holder.textViewTableSeats.setText(model.getTableSeats());
    holder.textViewTableOccupied.setText(String.valueOf(model.isTableOccupied()));
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TableHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_table,parent,false);
    return new TableHolder(v);
}

class TableHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textViewTableNumber;
    TextView textViewTableSeats;
    TextView textViewTableOccupied;

    public TableHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTableNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_table_number);
        textViewTableSeats = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_table_seats);
        textViewTableOccupied = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_table_occupied);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && onItemCLickListener!=null){
                    onItemCLickListener.onItemClick( getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position );
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
public interface OnItemCLickListener {
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemCLickListener onItemClickListener){
    this.onItemCLickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
```

}

Comment: if I understood correctly, then you do not need to do this in the adapter! it is better to do after getting the list for the adapter, to go through the list and find out whether all the elements are "have a boolean value = true". Need to see TableAdapter, then I will say how it make.